# How to acknowledge contributors of ideas (not code) to R package (using roxygen2)?

Tags: r, cran, roxygen2

Someone can help with an R package in a number of ways, including

1. A substantial body of original code/ideas (`author` or `contributor`)
2. Some trivial code (e.g. fixing a typo) (possibly `contributor`)
3. No code, but providing ideas or domain expertise ( `??` )

In the first instance, an `author` role would be most appropriate. In `roxygen2` this could look like so (`aut`):

```
Authors@R: c(
    person("Hadley", "Wickham", , "hadley@rstudio.com", c("aut", "cre"), comment = c(ORCID = "0000-0003-4757-117X")),
    person("Romain", "Fran\u00e7ois", role = "aut", comment = c(ORCID = "0000-0002-2444-4226")),
    person("Lionel", "Henry", role = "aut"),
    person("Kirill", "M\u00fcller", role = "aut", comment = c(ORCID = "0000-0002-1416-3412")),
    person("RStudio", role = c("cph", "fnd"))
    )
```

In the second case, a `contributor` role may (or may not) be appropriate. e.g.

```
Authors@R: c(
    person("Some", "One", , "someone@rstudio.com", c("ctb"))
```

But when someone helps with ideas/discussion/domain expertise, but ***hasn't*** contributed code (case 3), is a `contributor` role still appropriate, and if not, does this change if the ideas shaped the direction of the package - i.e. their ideas were ***very*** important despite them not writing the code.

#### What I know so far

The [Library of Congress](http://www.loc.gov/marc/relators/relaterm.html) defines `contributor` as

> A person, family or organization responsible for making contributions to the resource. This includes those whose work has been contributed to a larger work, such as an anthology, serial publication, or other compilation of individual works. If a more specific role is available, prefer that, e.g. editor, compiler, illustrator

Another possibility is `conceptor`

> A person or organization responsible for the original idea on which a work is based, this includes the scientific author of an audio-visual item and the conceptor of an advertisement

But this seems to indicate the *whole* work/package is based on their idea (which *could* be true, but not necessarily)

#### Other references

[Hadley](http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/description.html) defines contributors as

> those who have made smaller contributions, like patches.

#### Question

What is the appropriate role for someone whose *only* input is ideas (not code), and are there ways other roles for attributing due credit to those who provide important ideas to an R package(e.g. note in `README.md`, a separate file e.g. `CONTRIBUTIONS` file in root directory, something else??)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**tl;dr** I'd choose between `aut` and `ctb` depending on the magnitude of the contribution (as @Dason says, `ctb`s need not have written code). Because you said "their ideas were **very** important", it sounds like `aut` would be appropriate.

LOC references are fine, but *direct* guidance from R-Core is in `?person` and in Kurt Hornik's (an R-core member) [R Journal article](https://journal.r-project.org/archive/2012-1/RJournal_2012-1_Hornik~et~al.pdf) (these sources have more detail than [Writing R Extensions](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-exts.html#The-DESCRIPTION-file), which just says "See `?person` for more information."). From Hornik's article:

> In general, while all MARC relator codes are supported, the following usage is suggested when giving the roles of persons in the context of authoring R
>   packages:
>
> - "aut" (Author): Full authors who have made substantial contributions to the package and
>     should show up in the package citation.
> - "ctb" (Contributor): Authors who have made
>     smaller contributions (**such as** code patches etc.) but should not show up in the package
>     citation [emphasis added]

None of the other roles (`com`, `cph`, `cre`, `ctr`, `dtc`, `fnd`, `rev`, `ths`, `trl`) seem relevant here.

I don't think there is any other standardized venue for providing contribution info, but you could add information either to the overall package help file [aliased to *pkgname*-package](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-exts.html#Documenting-packages) or in the comment field for a package contributor:

> The ‘comment’ field can be used for “arbitrary” additional
>        information about persons.

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing in the description for contributors that says they need to write code as far as I can tell.